# c# stop process after running

Tags: c#, process

I have the problem that I want to unzip a zip file with 7za.exe and after that I want to kill the process. If I am using code like in the following, I have the problem that the process got killed before the process unzips the file.

I have already tried to use HasExited or WaitForExit, but no chance. Has anyone an idea? The only working way is to use a Thread.Sleep(1000) function, which I can't use because it slows some other processes.

```
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo zipper = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(@"##archzip.text##");
            zipper.Arguments = string.Format("x " + (PathOfFile) + "  -o" + (NewPathOfFile) + "");
            zipper.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            System.Diagnostics.Process proc = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(zipper);
            proc.Kill();
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you need to kill the process? Doesn't it exit by itself after unzipping?

Comment: If you find yourself killing a process that is expected to exit by itself, you're doing something wrong.

Comment: Why not unzipping the file directly using code, instead of using an external tool just for that? (There are some pretty good libs available for c#, e.g. https://www.nuget.org/packages/DotNetZip)

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I can only use system classes, that's the reason why I chose to use 7za.exe..

Answer (score 0):

You can try the code below

```
using System.IO.Compression;

public static void Decompress(FileInfo fileToDecompress)
{
    using (FileStream originalFileStream = fileToDecompress.OpenRead())
    {
        string currentFileName = fileToDecompress.FullName;
        string newFileName = currentFileName.Remove(currentFileName.Length - fileToDecompress.Extension.Length);

        using (FileStream decompressedFileStream = File.Create(newFileName))
        {
            using (GZipStream decompressionStream = new GZipStream(originalFileStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
            {
                decompressionStream.CopyTo(decompressedFileStream);
                Console.WriteLine("Decompressed: {0}", fileToDecompress.Name);
            }
        }
        }
}
```

If you want to decompress a folder, you can use the command line below:

```
ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(@"C:\temp\file\9906759_Testpraefix_14028604.zip", @"C:\temp\file\extract\9906759_Testpraefix_14028604");
```

Comment: thank you very much for you example! but unfortunately it doesn't work with DOC600ZIP files.. the size of the files after unzip is 0 kilobytes..

Comment: @dankoe, what is the specification for this file? Thanks.

Comment: its a ZIP file with an .doc inside. I also could rename the file to .ZIP but the file after unzipping is further broken. Thanks in advance.

Comment: where can I get a sample of this file to perform a test?

Comment: I've sent you an email :) Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @dankoe, I have saw that you are trying to decompress a folder, so you can use the line as I've included in the answer. Hope it is helpful.

Comment: Also, you can use this method directly like this: System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(@"C:\temp\file\9906759_Testpraefix_14028604.zip", @"C:\temp\file\extract\9906759_Testpraefix_14028604");